# How can I address wildly varying space above and beneath section headings?

Tags: xetex

I'm using xelatex with the book class. The structure of my document is basically

```
\chapter{Chapter 1}

some text

\section{Section 1a}

some text

\section{Section 1b}

some text
```

Everything is for the most part formatted nicely, but I've got extremely inconsistent space above and below my section headings. In a few places, like the picture here, it looks terrible. How can I address this?

[image: these are two sections]

Edit: I'd linked to MWE. Since the section breaks needed sections to show the problem, my MWE was fairly long. Here is the section that was causing problems:

```
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\filcenter\it}{}{8ex}{\fontsize{24}{30}\selectfont}%
[\vfill]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0ex}{0ex}
```

The `\vfill`, along with `\fillpage` set presumably by the `book` documentclass, was causing the problem. The fix was to alter the second line to replace the `vfill` with an explicit measurement and to then set `\raggedbottom`.

```
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\filcenter\it}{}{8ex}{\fontsize{24}{30}\selectfont}%
[\vspace{20pt plus \textheight}]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0ex}{0ex}

\raggedbottom
```

Comment: Can you please show a _complete_ but minimal example that gives this result? In particular, it can be interesting to know what comes on the next page.

Comment: You presumably have a large non floating oobject on the next page that is preventing a good page break, but as you have shown no example, it is hard to help.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, the next page has another section. I will see if I can reproduce this at a smaller scale.

Comment: OK so the section (and its first few lines) presumably do not fit on the page shown,  and (in code not shown) you are using `\flushbottom` (or a class that defaults to flushbottom) so vertical space stretches to bring the last line to the bottom of a page, just as word spaces stretch to bring words to the right margin.  You could use `\clearpage` here or `\raggedbottom` as a global setting or ...

Comment: please don't make an external link, add to your question as a code block. The question is archived forever and won't make sense without the example.

Comment: don't ignore `Package fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt):`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I feel like `\raggedbottom` is definitely the answer, but I cannot seem to set this. I have littered by code with `\raggedbottom` and it just won't take. Do you have a moment to take a look?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I fixed the headheight issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard answer is to add `\raggedbottom` (or if ragged bottom is not acceptable on stylistic reasons, you need to write enough words to fill the page)

However you have

```
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\filcenter\it}{}{8ex}{\fontsize{24}{30}\selectfont}%
[\vfill]
```

which adds the strongly stretchy vfill spacing after every section head, this stretches more than the space added at the bottom of a page by `\raggedbottom` (which is `\vskip \z@ \@plus.0001fil`)  so all the space is stretched around section heads.

Use a finite stretch, then even the `.0001fil` (the smallest possible infinite stretch) added by `\raggedbottom` will stretch and the space around section headings will not stretch on ragged pages.

[image]

```
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\filcenter\it}{}{8ex}{\fontsize{24}{30}\selectfont}%
[\vspace{0pt plus \textheight}]
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.

Comment: @Shay you see why we always ask for a full example, you would _never_ have got that answer from the original question (it would have been closed as duplicate of one of the existing questions with a "use \raggedbottom" answer:-)

Comment: But now there isn't even a link to an example ....